# req.body.name is showing undefinded, even with body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

trying to get user by its id from employee.ejs and up to user data entered below (in employee.ejs) should be fixed to current user
when i'm creating users there is no any kind of problems there, but when i'm trying to create their offenses in employee.ejs req.body.id is undefined but in the same page req.body.title and req.body.description is getting roght data

app.js

```
const errorhandler = require('../utils/errorHandler')
const Employee = require('../models/Employee')
const Offense = require('../models/Offense')



module.exports.getEmployee = async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const employees = await Employee.find({})

        // TODO: FIRST SET POST PAGE BECAUSE WHEN I POST OFFENSE, IT IDENTIFICATES THE CORRECT-EMPLOYEE
        const offenses = await Offense.find({
            employee: req.body.id
        })
        console.log(req.body.id)
        // console.log(offenses)

        employees.map(async employee => {
            const fullname = employee.name + employee.surname + employee.fathername

            if (req.params.worker === fullname.replace(/\s/g, '')) {
                console.log('ok')
                res.render('post', {
                    employee: employee,
                    offenses: offenses
                })
            } else {
                console.log('smth wrong')
            }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        errorhandler(res, e)
    }
}



module.exports.postEmployee = async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const employee = await Employee.findOne({
            _id: req.body.id
        })

        console.log(employee)

        const newoffense = new Offense({
            title: req.body.title,
            description: req.body.description,
            employee: employee
        })

        console.log(newoffense)

        // TODO: it's wrong getting right-employee and its offenses, make em right

        await newoffense.save()
        res.redirect('', res.status(201))
    } catch (e) {
        errorhandler(res, e)
    }
}
```

employee.ejs

```
<form action="/compose-offense" method="post">

    <h1 class="employee-name"><%= employee.name + ' ' + employee.surname + ' ' + employee.fathername         %> -
        <%= employee.workfield %></h1>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="id" value="<%= employee.id %>">


    <div class="form-group" id="compose">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" required>

        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control offense-control" name="description" id="" cols="2" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button class="btn" type="submit">Publish</button>

</form>


<div>
    <% if (offenses.length === 0) { %>

    <h3>No-offense</h3>

    <% } else { %>
    <% offenses.map(offense => { %>

    <h4><% offense.title %></h4>

    <% }) %>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show how you use the bodyparser in your express-app?

Comment: // --------------------------- PLUGINS

app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')